# How can I get bash to evaluate a PM2 command stored in a Variable?

Tags: 16.04, server, bash, environment-variables

I'm setting up a server config with cloud init and am running commands one after another in the config file.

One of the commands I need to run to setup my server's environment is PM2 to keep a node server app online after reboot. I am able to have PM2 output a special command I need to run and am storing that command in a variable to run in the next line.

Command 1: (Storing the Output)

```
pm2response=$(pm2 startup systemd)
```

Command 2: (Executing the response command and trimming extra logging)

```
${pm2response#*Execute the following command:}
```

When I run Command 2 in my playground server, it outputs the error

```
[PM2][ERROR] Init system not found
```

I don't understand why I can't store the command output in a variable and execute the variable. I have manually copied the exact command I need to run into the console and successfully executed it. It's just storing it in a variable that doesn't work.

Command I need to execute as a variable: (This works successfully)

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
```

Command I tried executing as a variable: (Has errors)

```
var='sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username'
$var
```

Why won't this work?

### Update

I got the $var to work using double quotes in my server.

```
var="sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username"
$var #works!
```

Although this is just an example I was testing in a playground server. For clarity of the question, I'm really trying to evaluate Command 2:

```
${pm2response#*Execute the following command:}
```

Reference for Command 2:
I'm using the shell parameter substitution so I can remove logging. This is the output without the shell parameter substitution.

`echo $pm2response`: (will output)

```
[PM2] Init System found: systemd [PM2] You have to run this command as root. Execute the following command: sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
```

So by adding shell parameter substitution,
`echo ${pm2response#*Execute the following command:}`: (will output)

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
```

Comment: Try `var=$(sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin 
 usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username)`

Comment: Maybe it's me who does not understand @George :) but I think your first comment is not right - they don't want to assign the output of the command to the variable but the command itself

Comment: @zanna done so!

Answer (score 1):

Try either of these lines:

```
var="sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username"

$var

var1=$("sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username")

$var1
```

The error on the one you used happens because expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that:

```
var='sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username'
$var
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I got it to work with the $var test. Although my main goal is to get it to work with ${pm2response#*Execute the following command:}. I need to use this syntax because I have to remove extra logging. I've tried using $({pm2response#*Execute the following command:})  but this doesn't work in this case.

Comment: then what of this `$PATH` part does OP not expect it to expand @zanna? And the last line is just a repeat of what the OP used above and not an answer, the first two are.